# Constructing a fractal

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, fractals

I have a fractal I am considering on $[0,1]$ by making "recursive tent functions".

I want to construct an explicit sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ from the following three, I am struggling to get a closed form, despite my intuition for what the graph "should" look like. I also am interested in properties of this function.

$f_0(x)= 2x\chi_{[0,1/2)}+(-2x+2)\chi_{[1/2,1]}$ which looks like two lines linked together at $1/2$, the first piece is increasing and second is decreasing.
Now we cut $f_0$ "dyadically" to obtain:
$f_1(x)=2x\chi_{[0,1/4)}+(-2x+1)\chi_{[1/4,1/2)}+(2x-1)\chi_{[1/2,3/4)}+(-2x+2)\chi_{[3/4,1)}$

We repeat this again, cutting $f_1$ "dyadically" to obtain:

$f_2(x)=(2x)\chi_{[0,1/8)}+(-2x+1/2)\chi_{[1/8,1/4)}+(2x-1/2)\chi_{[1/4,3/8)}...$ and so on.

I want $f_n$, I know it will be similar to $f_n(x)=(2x)\chi_{[0,2^{-n})}+...+(-2x+2)\chi_{[\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},1]}$.

I also cautiously guess $f_n\rightarrow f=0$ uniformly (as I am pretty sure we have pointwise convergence). Assuming we have uniform convergence, this means that $\int_{0}^{1}f_n d\mu=0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Also $\forall n$ we have $f_n$ is not monotonic, yet the limit function $f=0$. $f_n$ is differentiable, as for each sub-interval, we have linear functions.

**FRACTAL**: [image: I have shown the fractal at various stages in construction][image: This is the function sequence I am considering]

I realize the fractal as drawn cannot be considered as a function, but perhaps can be parameterized in a clever way where I can still study some of its analytic properties.

Comment: Does [this construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve) look like what you want?

Comment: similar, but not quite! Consider two lines, both with slope $2$ which are joined at $x=1/2$, and then, we go to $x=1/4$, and $x=3/4$ to make two new "tents", and repeat this process indefinitely.

Comment: I don't see a "fractal" here but, rather, a sequence of [triangle waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) converging uniformly to zero. I don't really see a question, either. :)